# Send button respond on enter press

Tags: html

I have the following html:

```
<button type="submit" id="go" onclick="send()">Send</button>
```

I want this button to also call the send method on pressing enter. How would I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen form onsubmit event:

```
<form onsubmit="send()">
    ...
</form>
```

In general if you deal with a form `onsubmit` is your friend. `onclick` event is not a proper way of submitting forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript

```
if(event.keyCode == 13)
{
    $("#go").click();
}

function send()
{
    alert("hello");
}
```

Example:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N95qV/1/)